# Why is my React table not updating after adding or deleting objects in a Django database using axios and React Table?

Tags: reactjs, django, react-typescript, react-table

Putting data from a django database into a react table

I tried generating a JsonResponse with the data and display it at api/data. The data gets displayed on the url correctly.
Then I tried loading the data inside the TableComponent using axios such as:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await axios.get('/api/data');
                setData(response.data);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

The data gets loaded into a tableInstance like this:

```
const tableInstance = useTable({
        columns,
        data,
    })
```

It worked the first time but when I add or delete objects using the admin panel it gets displayed correctly at the api/data address but it won't show inside my table.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `setData()` only inside this `useEffect` then this will happen only once after the component mount.
to update the UI (redisplay the table) or let's say rerender the component, you have to update its state. Consider calling `fetchData()` each time an object is deleted/added (db update)
 or if your delete/add endpoints are returning the new data as response, then this will be better, since you can make advantage  and update the state directly with the response.